# Incrementally upgrading to Rails assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a fairly complex Rails web application that's nearly 4 years old :).  It is live with many customers using it on a daily basis, so I have to be a little less cavalier when I made radical changes to it.

I have managed to get it migrated to rails 3.2.2 and still functional, but there is a lot of code that still uses Scriptaculous, Prototype's Ajax calls (for pagination, for instance) and so on.

I want to slowly migrate all these to using jQuery UJS and Coffeescript, but I have to do these changes piecemeal, preferably one controller at a time across multiple "releases".

But I see that turning on assets is a boolean switch.

How did you migrate your existing code to assets pipeline without breaking a lot of code?  What are the precautions I should take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These episodes of railscasts helped me a lot.

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1
3. http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2

The summary:

Set your Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'yui-compressor' # i'm using yui for compressor
end
```

move your assets (javascripts, fonts, css, images, etc) to app/assets, mine like this:

```
app/
  assets/
    fonts/
    images/
    javascripts/
    stylesheets/
```

and on the css, change the url helper to something like font-url, image-url, or assets-url. You can find more information here, https://github.com/rails/sass-rails. Maybe you will want to use a staging server to check if the assets pipelining working fine, at least for the static assets your app serve. Also to make sure there's javascript file loaded more than once. (It gave me a headache before when I upgrading to assets pipeline).

hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not too late, here is the trick we have found to have asset pipeline enabled, still having many css and js in public folder :

In order to keep the "old" tag helpers for static files, we alias them before they are overridden by the asset pipeline. We add this snippet above the `require 'rails/all'` in application.rb :

```
require 'rails'

ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
  alias_method :without_asset_pipeline_js,  :javascript_include_tag
  alias_method :without_asset_pipeline_css, :stylesheet_link_tag
  alias_method :without_asset_pipeline_img, :path_to_image
end
```

Thus, in our views, we still have access to them. But we would have to change all our tags... So, we add an initializer to restore the "old" tags and prefixed the "new" tags with 'asset_' (or whatever). Now, we can have both static assets files in public/ and assets managed by the asset pipeline.

For now, we didn't meet trouble with this approach (except that it doesn't work with images !), but we are the beginning...

Comment: This worked for me, although it seems kludgy. I wish this functionality was built in.